# Find and classify critical points of $\ f(x,y)=\cos(x^2 + y^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to classify the critical points of$\ f$, but the problem says to only consider the points$\ (0,0),\left(\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}\right)$.

So, long story short, after using the second derivative test I got that$\ D=0$ at both critical points.

How should I proceed with this problem?

Comment: $f$ is constant along every circle centered at the origin and a sinusoid along every line through the origin. What does that tell you about its critical points?

Comment: You can try with the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test)

Comment: @caverac The Hessian has a null eigenvalue in bath cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $(0,0)$, the function has a local maximum, because $f(0,0)=1$ and $f(x,y)<1$ if $(x,y)$ is near to (but distinct from) $(0,0)$.

At $\left(\sqrt{\frac\pi2},\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\right)$, $f$ has a local minimum, although not a strict one. In fact $f(x,y)=-1$ at every point of the circle $x^2+y^2=\pi$ (to which the point $\left(\sqrt{\frac\pi2},\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\right)$ belongs) and $f(x,y)>-1$ at all other points near $\left(\sqrt{\frac\pi2},\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks, but the critical points that I wanted to take into consideration where: $\ (0,0),\left(\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}\right)$. Your answer did help me undestand the problem, thanks.

Comment: That is what I meant. I shall edit my post.

Comment: But, isn't $\ f \left(\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{π}{2}}\right)=-1$ ? wouldn't there be a minimum at this point?

Comment: Whoops! I did it again. Yes, it is a minimum, but my argument is correct. I shall edit my answer once again. Sorry about that,

Comment: Yeah, your second argument (before corrections) made me flip out a little bit, but thanks for the help, now I get it!